# PortableRenderer IceFaces

Tags: web-services, servlets, push, icefaces, renderer

I am trying to implement an IceFaces Project where I have a java web service doing push-notifications.

I have a client that logs in and sends a push notification through the web service to others.

My problem is that I discovered that I have to use portableRenderer() because the web service is outside the JSF context. It needs a ServletContext as argument.

I tried to do it but it seems to have problem in passing the context from client to web service because ServletContext is not an available type (integer, string, boolean, ...).

The error returned is NullPointerException. Any suggestion?

I have tried to follow some guides on internet and PushRenderer() locally works good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself.
I wrote to IceFaces developers and they very kindly answered my questions. So I report here if anyone has the same problem.
It is not possible to push notificate with the IceFaces Renderer outside the JSF context. It has to be done locally.